# Why the "select" tag has no "placeholder" attribute?

Tags: html

All the ways to show the default value in the select tag propose to use a dumb option tag. Why there is no default way just to show a placeholder?

Comment: According to Mozilla Dev Network, placeholder is not a valid attribute on a <select> input. This is how it was designed by developers of web standards. It's a little strange to consider <option> as a dump way without any comment on why this is so. Please read how to ask a good question here - [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<select name="plan" id="plan">
  <option selected disable hidden>Choose plan</option>
  <option>Free</option>
  <option>Premium</option>
  <option>silver</option>
  <option>gold</option>
</select>
```

Now your problem is solved

Comment: The question is why, not how.

Comment: We can add placeholder only in inputs not in other tags

Answer (score 0):

```html
<select required>
  <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select...</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The question asks why, not how.